# iterate throuh multiple queryset in django

Tags: django

my queryset output comes in this way

```
[<QuerySet [<Video: paid work>]>, <QuerySet [<Video: paid>, <Video: free>]>]
```

how I can loop throut it in template?

```
{% for item in object_list %}
{{item.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

this is not showing anything

Comment: Can't you just nest two loops? `{% for qs in object_list %}{% for item in qs %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuerySet's [union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) method, which uses SQL's `UNION` operator to combine results of two or more QuerySets.